# php and mysql error for registration form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, registration

when i press register on my php form im getting this error:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in /home/changj/public_html/register.php on line 26 No database
>   selected

Below is the register.php script line 26 but unsure how to fix the error

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)> 0 ) {
```

any ideas thanks.

Comment: **EXACT DUPLICATE** of [Register/Login Form PHP MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599761/register-login-form-php-mysql) You don't see many of them here.

Answer (score 2):

I guess `$sql` is a string. Try this,

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)> 0 ) { .... }
```

but [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. An alternative is to use, [mysqli_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO::query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: As an adivce: In general the user should always consider Exception Handling.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a database selected: "No database selected"

Make sure that you have a mysql_connect() and a mysql_select_db() anywhere before your statement.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599815/1190388)

From [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) documentation:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or **FALSE on error.**

The query is wrong. Change it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the database?

```
mysql_select_db("databaseName");
```

Or, if you're using "raw queries", you may be missing this line:

```
mysql_query("USE databaseName");
```